# Strange Error in Sharepoint Object Model while deleting list Item

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, shared-libraries

I am getting very strange error, worked out for last couple of hours to fix this

"Updates are currently disallowed on GET requests.  To allow updates on a GET, set the 'AllowUnsafeUpdates' property on SPWeb. "

```
  Public Shared Sub DeleteListItem(ByVal listname As SPList, ByVal intItemID As Integer)

        Using MySite As New SPSite(SPContext.GetContext(System.Web.HttpContext.Current).Web.Url)

            Using MyWeb As SPWeb = MySite.OpenWeb()
                MyWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = True
                Dim itemColforGivenList As SPListItemCollection
                Dim query As New SPQuery()
             query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value Type='Counter'>" &    
                intItemID & "</Value></Eq></Where>"
                MyWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = True
                itemColforGivenList = listname.GetItems(query)
                If itemColforGivenList.Count > 0 Then
                    For i As Integer = listname.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                        If listname.Items(i).ID = intItemID Then
                            MyWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = True
                            listname.Items.Delete(i)
                            listname.Update()
                            MyWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = False
                        End If
                    Next

                End If

            End Using
        End Using
```

Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `MyWeb.Update();` directly after `MyWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;` ? It's possible that the `listname.Update()` call is checking this property by pulling directly from the web and not the object representing that web you have in the current context. This does create a couple concerns as you will need to call update on that web/list multiple times to enable and disable the property and also delete the item so keep that in mind.